# Hive: unable to fetch column that is not present in GROUP BY

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have a table in hive called `purchase_data` that has a list all the purchases made.
I need to query this table and find the cust_id, product_id and price of the most expensive product purchased by a customer.
The data in `purchase_data` table looks like:

```
cust_id         product_id      price   purchase_data
--------------------------------------------------------
aiman_sarosh    apple_iphone5s  55000   01-01-2014
aiman_sarosh    apple_iphone6s  65000   01-01-2017
jeff_12         apple_iphone6s  65000   01-01-2017
jeff_12         dell_vostro     70000   01-01-2017
missy_el        lenovo_thinkpad 70000   01-02-2017
```

I have written the code below, but it is not fetching the right rows.
Some rows are getting repeated:

```
select master.cust_id, master.product_id, master.price
from
(
  select cust_id, product_id, price
  from purchase_data
) as master
join
(
  select cust_id, max(price) as price
  from purchase_data
  group by cust_id
) as max_amt_purchase
on max_amt_purchase.price = master.price;
```

output:

```
aiman_sarosh    apple_iphone6s  65000.0
jeff_12         apple_iphone6s  65000.0
jeff_12         dell_vostro     70000.0
jeff_12         dell_vostro     70000.0
missy_el        lenovo_thinkpad 70000.0
missy_el        lenovo_thinkpad 70000.0
Time taken: 21.666 seconds, Fetched: 6 row(s)
```

Is there something wrong with the code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `row_number()`:

```
select pd.*
from (select pd.*,
             row_number() over (partition by cust_id order by price_desc) as seqnum
      from purchase_data pd
     ) pd
where seqnum = 1;
```

This returns one row per `cust_id`, even if there are ties.  If you want multiple rows when there are ties, then use `rank()` or `dense_rank()` instead of `row_number()`.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon, I changed the code, and its working. I have posted the solution. :)

Comment: @aiman . . . Using a join and aggregation when a ranking function will do is a waste of resources and just makes the query more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code, its working now:

```
select master.cust_id, master.product_id, master.price
from
purchase_data as master,
(
  select cust_id, max(price) as price
  from purchase_data
  group by cust_id
) as max_price
where master.cust_id=max_price.cust_id and master.price=max_price.price;
```

output:

```
aiman_sarosh    apple_iphone6s  65000.0
missy_el        lenovo_thinkpad 70000.0
jeff_12         dell_vostro     70000.0

Time taken: 55.788 seconds, Fetched: 3 row(s)
```